# Between 2 arrays, get elements that only appear in the first array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 objects and each has a property that holds an array, and I'd like to get the elements in the array property that only appear in the first object (elements that appear only in the first json object):

```
obj1:
{
    "total" : 2065,
    "delegators" : [
        "tx01",
        "tx02",
        "tx03",
        "tx04",
        "tx05",
        "tx06",
        "tx07",
        "tx08",
        ...
    ]
}

obj2:
{
    "total" : 1109,
    "delegators" : [
        "tx03",
        "tx08",
        ...
    ]
}
```

This is my code so far:

```
export const findUncommonAddresses = (obj1, obj2) => {
    let arr1 = obj1.delegators
    let arr2 = obj2.delegators
    let difference = arr1.filter(addr1 => !arr2.includes(addr1));
    return difference;
```

I'm not sure if my method is correct. Reason being, the difference in the `total`
is 947, but when I check the length of `difference`, it is not that value.

Comment: Those are regular arrays. There are [no such things as a JSON-'arrays'](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this

```js
const data = {obj1:
{
    "total" : 2065,
    "delegators" : [
        "tx01",
        "tx02",
        "tx03",
        "tx04",
        "tx05",
        "tx06",
        "tx07",
        "tx08",
    ]
},

obj2:
{
    "total" : 1109,
    "delegators" : [
        "tx03",
        "tx08",
    ]
}
}

const result = data.obj1.delegators.filter(d => !data.obj2.delegators.includes(d))

console.log(result)
```